# Запись элементов из базы данных в список

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, запрос

Для реализации функции автозаполнения потребовалось записать данные из базы данных в список. Запрос является обьектом класса QSqlQuery и и именно после выполнения запроса он не конвертируется в стрингу. В идеале ответ с кодом, как построить цыкл занесения в список я разберусь, но как внести туда данные с запроса - буду благодарна за помощь.

Comment: Ваш код запроса покажите, чтобы было видно, что именно вы пытаетесь привести к строке.

Comment: _if(db.open()){
        qry=new QSqlQuery;
        qry->prepare("SELECT Name FROM surface");
        qry->exec();_

Comment: 1. Добавьте код в вопрос. 2. Если не нужна подстановка параметров в запрос, в `prepare` нет необходимости. 3. Это весь код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае получение данных из базы можно организовать следующим образом.

```
QStringList list;
QSqlQuery query("select Name from surface");

while (query.next()) {
    list << query.value(0).toString();
}
```